# Recurrence relationship : guess fails with multiple terms

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

in a non homogeneous recurrence, if the guess $A2^n$ fails, we replace it by $(An + B)2^n$, then if it fails again we replace it by $(An² + Bn + C)2^n$ and so on.

But what if a guess composed of multiple terms fails?
For example, for $2^n + n$ i'm guessing $A2^n + Bn + C$ but it fails. What's my next guess?

Thanks